# Unmute embedded Vine by default

Tags: javascript, html5-video, vine

I want to [embed Vine videos on my site](http://www.schmutzie.com/weblog/2013/2/7/how-to-embed-vine-videos-just-about-anywhere.html). By default the audio is disabled (with good reason),

I wish to be evil and unmute the video when the page loads,

The video seems to make use of videojs, is there a way to do this through their api?

Otherwise is there a way to simulate a click on the unmute 'button' once the page has loaded?

Inspecting the element gives:

```
<a href="#" class="mute-button off"></a>
```

I was thinking along the lines of js `.click()` method?

Answer (score 3):

You can add the parameter mute as follows:
https://vine.co/v/h2t1zY5gOTB?mute=0

Answer (score 2):

So far, there is no way I've found. The button is within the iframe and therefore cannot be accessed to trigger the click event. You'll also notice that clicking on the embed links you to the video viewer on Vine's website.

I changed the mute button's class to "mute-button on" in developer tools and there isn't even a audio on state in the CSS for the embed. THis leads me to believe that at this time, there is no infrastructure in Vine embed for unmuting the video.

If you drill down in the inspector you can get the url to the video source and link to it in your own custom video player. That's the approach i am taking. Hopefully in the future Vine will provide more options for embedded videos.

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of Vine you can simply choose the option to have it autoplay the audio, but to do it yourself try including `?audio=1` at the end of the src for the video.

Example:
[Embed Vine Batdad video](https://vine.co/v/hj7q1mqb7KH/embed)

Comment: This works on firefox but not on chrome. Seems we are close to a solution ;)